# What relationship between firestore snapshotlistener's lifecycle and pricing?

Tags: java, android, firebase, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore

In my activities, I have a list of strings which represent firestore documents to which I want to attach snapshot listeners. I use Acivity - ModelView - Repository structure. In the acitivity's onCreate, I ask ViewModelProvider for the appropriate ViewModel. In the ViewModel constructor, I make a call to get a repository (as per the "Android room with a view" tutorial"). My repositories are in charge of attaching firestore listeners and sync the online data into my local DB (android room).

I used to have memory leaks with those listeners, i.e. every time a firestore document changed, my repository was trying to download two, three, four..copies of it into the local DB! I solved that problem by making a call from my activities' onDestroy all the way up to the repository to remove the listeners.

**My question** is about the pricing of this solution. I read on the FireBase website that a snapshot listener will count at least as one "document read" everytime it is launched, even if no changes to the document are ever made. Basically, I am removing and re-attaching a dozen or so listeners (to the exact same documents) every time a user switches activities in my app. Does this mean I am paying a document read for every one of those activity changes even if the 30-minute limit isn't up yet?

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMessageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MessageViewModel.class);
    // ....
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    mMessageViewModel.removeListeners();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public MessageViewModel (Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = new MessageRepository(application);
}
public void removeListeners(){
    mRepository.removeListeners();
}
// ...
```

**Repository**

```
private List<ListenerRegistration> my_listeners;
private List<String> my_list;
MessageRepository(Application application) {
    MessageRoomDatabase db = MessageRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    mMessageDao = db.messageDao();
    firedb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    attachListeners();
}
public void attachListeners(){
    for(String item : my_list){
        colRef = firedb.collection("items").document(item).collection("sub-items");
        ListenerRegistration my_listener_registration = colRef
            .addSnapshotListener(myListener);
        my_listeners.add(my_listener_registration);
    }
}
public void removeListeners(){
    for(ListenerRegistration my_listener : my_listeners){
        my_listener.remove();
    }
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you attach a listener, the Firestore client has to connect to the server to check if the documents observed by that listener have been modified. Since the server has to read the document for that, you will indeed be charged for a document read for each document that you observe.

If you don't want this, you can consider telling the client to read from the cache by [specifying that in the source options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options).

> ```
> DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
>
> // Source can be CACHE, SERVER, or DEFAULT.
> Source source = Source.CACHE;
>
> // Get the document, forcing the SDK to use the offline cache
> docRef.get(source).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
>    ...
> ```

Since this reads from the local cache, you won't be charged for a read on the server, but of course that means you may be serving stale data.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I don't know if this counts as a separate question - but what would be the accepted way to launch my listeners in an activity-lifecycle independent way in order to make full use of the 30min listening? That is, without memory leaks like losing my reference to the listener.

Comment: I think you pretty much provide your own answer there: you'll need to host your listener in a component whose lifecycle is separate from your activity. I'm no Android expert, but imagine that there'll be something MVVM'ish in Jetpack or AndroidX.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so if I use default (Source.DEFAULT;) and I have 10k records in server. Will it be counted as paid everytime when I load data or It will take care of new data only? (I am persisting data offline too.)

Comment: if you use a `getDocuments()` call with `Source.DEFAULT` the client has to check with the server, which has to read those documents. Hence it will count as reading each document. If you repeatedly need to do that, consider using a realtime listener since that'll often be more efficient in that scenario.