# How to avoid killing and relaunching firestore listeners on activity change?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-lifecycle

**Here is a use case from my app:**
I have a "roooms list" activity, where a user can see all the rooms he has joined, and upon clicking one of them, he enters the "chatroom" activity where he can chat with the other users in that room. Rooms are represented by firestore documents in my "rooms" collection, and messages sent in the room are a subcollection of that document. Room joining and leaving can only be done by the user's action, so technically speaking I can calculate a list of rooms that a user joined by using local information without querying firebase.

However, I want users to receive live updates of all the rooms they joined. For example, in the "rooms list" activity, they should be able to see the number of participants in that room, the names of the participants, etc.For this purpose, I currently run snapshot listeners on every room document that is in my list of joined rooms when the user enters the "rooms list" activity.

**The problem is** that, unless I'm mistaken, this is costing me dozens of new firestore reads every time the users navigates through the app and returns to the room list or chatroom activities, even when the data to which I'm listening hasn't actually changed.

Notes: I am using some activity - viewmodel - repository architecture that I detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419258/what-relationship-between-firestore-snapshotlisteners-lifecycle-and-pricing). I also use a single activity with 3 fragments for my main navigation component, which includes main activity, rooms list, and "my profile". I have been made aware of the "single activity" app design, but have not decided to pursue it fully.
(edit: I am using Android Room as a "single source of truth" for my UI, and my repository initiates firestore listeners which get data from firebase and write it into Room)

**My question is** therefore: is there an activity-independent feature in android that would enable me to set all my "background" firestore listeners a single time without resetting them in vain between activity changes, thus greatly increasing monthly costs?

**(Edit)**: I had in fact disabled firestore caching shortly after implementing Android Room into my app, concluding that the two were in conflict. Perhaps this was a big mistake. From my understanding of caching, here is what would happen with / without firestore caching enabled:

- With caching, I enter the "rooms list" activity, load the ten rooms I joined, then navigate through the app. When I return to the "rooms list" activity a few minutes later, my activity attempts to launch the listeners again, and firebase recognizes that no document updates have happened during that time, therefore costing me zero (or one?) document reads.
- Without caching, I enter the "rooms list" acitivty, load the ten rooms I joined, and then navigate through the app. When I return to the "rooms list" activity later, my activity launches the listeners again, and since caching is disabled, firebase simply returns to me the list of the ten rooms I joined once again, thus costing me 10 document reads in vain.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this, you can retain objects between activity configuration changes with [Android Jetpack's ViewModel component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).  This works for Firestore queries as well, though you will need a fair amount of plumbing to do this correctly.  A full discussion is too long for Stack Overflow, but you should watch [my talk about Firebase and Jetpack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NAjWzpm3jg) to get some of the story, then [check out the sample app](https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack).  The thing you will want to pay attention to is a custom `LingeringLiveData` object that sticks around for a while even after the last observer is detacted, so it won't close off the query immediately after a configuration change.

FWIW the Kotlin extensions for LiveData also "linger" in the same respect, but Android doesn't provide a similar solution for Java.

Comment: I do in fact use android jetpack's model with Android Room and LiveData. I will readily admit that first implementing it as a beginner to Android proved tricky, and I most likely made some mistakes along the way. I also disabled firebase caching after implementing Android Room. I updated my post with my understanding of how firestore caching works - could you confirm that the scenario I described is correct? Thanks !  (Apart from that, I will shortly be watching and reading the links you provided)

Comment: You have too many questions in your post now - they are not all necessarily related to each other.  I've answered the first, primary question about how to keep queries alive in the face of a configuration change.  I suggest splitting your other questions into different posts so that the whole thing is easier for others to understand when they land here from searches.